# Python argparse: How to make an initial parameter determine how many parameters come after?

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to do the following, where the `type` specified dictates what parameters I can use after.

For example, for `cmd1`, I'd expect a `param1` and `param2`.

For `cmd2`, I'd expect a `param3`, `param4`, `param5`, and `param6`.

For `cmd3`, I'd expect no parameters.

If I don't specify the expected parameters, an error should be shown.

---

Also, is there someway I could make it so that issuing a `-h` would show the different combinations allowed?

In all situations, there may be other tags that could be specified, such as `--id 5` or `--config 1`.

Is this possible with python's argparse?

I.e.,

```
python test.py --type cmd1 param1 param2 --id 5

python test.py --config 2 --type cmd2 param3 param4 param5 param6

python test.py --type cmd3 --config 1
```

Comment: You can use `nargs` parameter to `add_argument`. But also see sub-commands, they might be more suitable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: "Also, is there someway I could make it so that issuing a -h would show the different combinations allowed?" This happens automatically by default, whenever you get the rest configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of subcommands will get most of what you want.  Read the docs for explainations

```
#python test.py --type cmd1 param1 param2 --id 5
#python test.py --config 2 --type cmd2 param3 param4 param5 param6
#python test.py --type cmd3 --config 1

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--config', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--id', type=int)
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='type', required=True)
sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
sp1.add_argument('param1')
sp1.add_argument('param2')
sp2 = sp.add_parser('cmd2')
sp2.add_argument('parame1')
# etc
sp3 = sp.add_parser('cmd3')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

test cases

```
1535:~/mypy$ python3 stack70763135.py -h
usage: stack70763135.py [-h] [--config CONFIG] [--id ID] {cmd1,cmd2,cmd3} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd1,cmd2,cmd3}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --config CONFIG
  --id ID

1535:~/mypy$ python3 stack70763135.py --id 5 cmd1 foo1 foo2
Namespace(config=None, id=5, param1='foo1', param2='foo2', type='cmd1')
1535:~/mypy$ python3 stack70763135.py --config 2 cmd2 foo1
Namespace(config=2, id=None, parame1='foo1', type='cmd2')
1536:~/mypy$ python3 stack70763135.py --config 3 cmd3
Namespace(config=3, id=None, type='cmd3')
```

The help's might be more fragmented that what you want, but the info is all there.

`id` and `config` have to come before the `cmd` entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs), I believe. For example:

```
parser.add_argument('--cmd1', nargs=2)  # expects 2 parameters for this argument
```

nargs will save the parameters into a list (even if you set it to 1!). There are even special characters you can use for nargs, such as doing nargs='?' to get an indeterminate number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
parser.add_argument("--cmd1",nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.cmd1)
```

and running it:

```
>>> py parser.py --cmd1 onlyoneargument
usage: RecFcs.py [-h] [--cmd1 CMD1 CMD1]
RecFcs.py: error: argument --cmd1: expected 2 arguments
```

if we provide 2 arguments

```
>>> py parser.py --cmd1 one two
["one","two"]
```